# Do generic classes have a base class?

Tags: c#, interface, generics, constraints

I would like to pass a generic interface to a function:

```
private I<T> CreateStubRepository<T, I >()
 where I : aGenericBaseClass
```

So i was wondering if generic interfaces implement a base class or specific interface?

I know by using reflection you can test if it is a generic class but I dont see that helping me

Comment: Depends which generic interfaces... IComparable doesn't implement a base class, cause you can use it on any class

Comment: First of all, are you talking about abstracted classes or interfaces? Interfaces can't have base 'classes' they can only have additional interfaces. To be honest, I don't really understand the question, which classes/interfaces do you want to be able to use in this method and which classes/interfaces don't you want to be useable? An example of what you're trying to do would help us.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. If `I` is a generic base class already (let's say one having some generic type parameter `X`), then the return type `I<T>` would be "doubly-generic": `I<X><T>`. Thus `I<T>` surely isn't valid, syntactically?

Answer (score 1):

Well. What's the point of forcing the usage of *any* interface? I really do not get it (or your question).

You should more likely do something like this:

```
public interface IMyRepository<T>
{
}

public class Repository<T> : IMyRepository<T>
{
}


private IMyRepository<TEntity> CreateStubRepository<TEntity>()
{
     return new Repository<TEntity>();
}

var repos = CreateStubRepository<User>();
```

### Update

> thanks for your answer but thats not what I am asking. What I want to know is does a class that implements a generic interface have a base class or does it inherit from an interface? I dont want to force any interface its more a question of is the object passed generic

Classes do not inherit interfaces. They implement them. The different is subtle but important.

A class can only inherit another class. This means that if you do not specify that a class inherits from another it will still inherit from object. And that wont change no matter how many interfaces a class implement.

```
class MyClass : ICoolInterface // inherits object
class MyList : ArrayList, ISomeInterface // inherits ArrayList
class MyGenericList<T> : IList<T> // inherits object.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but thats not what I am asking. What I want to know is does a class that implements a generic interface have a base class or does it inherit from an interface? I dont want to force any interface its more a question of is the object passed generic.

Comment: @Desmon - You need to tell us what you're trying to do, because with the current state of your question there's only one answer - **No**.

Answer (score 0):

Generic or non-generic classes can implement or inherit from generic or non-generic interfaces and classes.  The only limitation is that the full type of any interface/class implemented/inherited from must be discernible given the full type of the class doing the implementing or inheriting.  For example, a Foo<Bar> might inherit from FooBase and implement IDisposable; a FnordDuffleBag might inherit from DuffleBag<Fnord> and implement IReachInto<Fnord>.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments I think i was going in the wrong direction, What I was hoping for was that when I applied  to a class the framework would know that it inherited from a base class or interface of say aGenericItemBaseClass before it constructed the class at runtime.

Yes I know that I can create a generic class with type parameters and use that but thats not what I was asking (although you may have got that impression from my posting).

At runtime I know that when using reflection I can determine if a class is generic by calling : IsGenericType which returns true if a type is generic.

So what I wanted to know which may have been explained poorly is, when using template types is there anyway to determine if that type is a generic type?  It appears the answer is No the IL interperates the class as generic not the compiler.